# C++ File Input/Output storing output in a directory

Tags: c++, file, output

I am working on a C++ HW assignment dealing with file I/O. I've never done this before, and is probably pretty obvious, but I would like to ask a quick question about including a path to my output and input files. In the example I am storing it in the c drive of a temp directory, though it is not showing up anywhere. Am I going about this wrong, or am I not looking in the right place in my c drive? Thx for the help, here a little copy of my code

```
ifstream in;
ofstream out;

 in.open("c:/temp/gradeBook.txt");
 if(in.fail());
 {
      cout << "Input file opening failed.\n";
      exit(1);

 }    

 out.open("c:/temp/gradeBook2.txt");
 if (out.fail());
 {
       cout << "Out put file opening failed. \n";
       exit(1);
 }  

 cout << "A new gradefile has been comepleted" << endl;

 calculate(in,out);

 out.close();
 in.close();

 system("PAUSE");
 return 0;
```

}

Comment: Code looks good to me. Maybe you get an error opening the input file. Try adding `system("PAUSE")` before the two calls to `exit(1)`.

Comment: Try is_open() instead of fail()...

Comment: `if(in.fail());` -- semicolon is wrong here! The same for `if (out.fail());`

Comment: Yes thanks for the tip. I'm getting an error opening input file, how would I go about fixing this?

Comment: would I have to put ! if I use is_open()?

Comment: @user: just remove it in any case, it is just wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the help, input is no longer failing

Comment: My output file is failing now, any idea whY?